# How can I get my VB GUI not to freeze while the program is running?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, user-interface, vb6, refresh

I am writing a program in Visual Studio 2012 with VB that opens and adjusts very large Excel files but starts with a GUI that allows the user to select placement of the file and the file that the data comes from. I also added a progress bar and a textbox to show the progress because it is helpful for seeing where issues arise and showing that something is actually occurring.

Unfortunately, though the pieces and the code are in place, as soon as the program begins running it freezes and neither shows nor types anything. At the end of the program (once it finished successfully) you can see that everything went as it should and was typed out. This is all in a single class as it is a fairly simple application.

I have tried adding System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) in the hope that the pause would allow for the program to update as it goes. Unfortunately this is not the case. How can I get the program to slow down long enough to pass through the visual updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is create a separate thread for your excel processing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btky721f.aspx

Edit:

Documentation for threading in VB6 (didn't see your VB6 tag, posting this just in case)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

**Why?**

Your main window is one thread on it's own, all the drawing and updating is done in this thread. If a block of code takes a while to execute, the whole thread is going to be blocked waiting for this code to finish executing, thus, nothing will refresh on the application

Right now, the Thread.Sleep(1000) call is just freezing your main window for a second more

By creating a separate thread for your excel processing, you are now freeing your main window so the user can continue to input things while it is being done.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Does the excel thread need to go in a wholly separate class from MainWindow in order to update properly or can I create two separate threads within that class and have one update the window data and the other handle processing?

Comment: I would create a separate class for it like ExcelProcess and create a thread on the public "Run" function or whatever you want to call it inside. Creating a class will also allow you to pass in parameters for your thread as member variables inside you class, which can be accessed inside your "Run" loop inside your thread. Plus, your code will be separated from one big file, so easier to read and edit later

Comment: If you want just to call a separate function, you may want to look here as I didn't experimented it yet and I have no access to Visual Studio for now. Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603606/how-to-put-this-function-inside-a-separated-thread